# Drop rows containing specific value in PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe like:

A     B        C
1     NA      9 
4     2         5
6     4        2
5     1     NA

I want to delete rows which contain value "NA". In this case first and the last row. How to implement this using Python and Spark?

---

Update based on comment:
Looking for a solution that removes rows that have the string: NA in any of the many columns.

Comment: What does NA mean? Does it mean a missing value for you? Or is it like that in your DataFrame? In that case your column B will be a String! Kindly confirm.

Comment: NA is not  a missing value. It's a string keyword. I want to drop all the rows that contain string "NA".

Comment: Also, NA could also be present in another column, not necessarily in column B so that row should also be dropped.

Comment: NA and 2 are different type, is the 2 or 4 a string as well? What is your DF definition pls?

Comment: Yes, so spark has labeled them as String because of "NA" present there. I want to remove "NA" so that the columns could be labeled as Integer. One way would be to replace "NA" with 0 everywhere. I am not able to implement it with correct syntax.

Comment: Can you show your structure. I prototype in Scala and keep on getting Any

Comment: You should add a minimum example and what you've tried so far. A simple filter will do the job

Answer (score 13):

Just use a dataframe [filter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter) expression:

```
l = [('1','NA','9')
    ,('4','2', '5')
    ,('6','4','2')
    ,('5','NA','1')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['A','B','C'])
#The following command requires that the checked columns are strings!
df = df.filter((df.A != 'NA') & (df.B != 'NA') & (df.C != 'NA'))
df.show()

+---+---+---+ 
|  A|  B|  C| 
+---+---+---+ 
|  4|  2|  5| 
|  6|  4|  2| 
+---+---+---+
```

@bluephantom: In the case you have hundreds of columns, just generate a string expression via list comprehension:

```
#In my example are columns need to be checked
listOfRelevantStringColumns = df.columns
expr = ' and '.join('(%s != "NA")' % col_name for col_name in listOfRelevantStringColumns)
df.filter(expr).show()
```

Comment: What if hundreds of columns?

Comment: I have updated my post. I think it is the best way to use a string expression for the filter method.

Comment: Agree, for sure.

Comment: What I am thinking is how do we get this to work and stop if the the first encountered match is found? I am looking nto it from Scala side

Comment: You want to stop after the first row based or the first column based match? Maybe it makes sense to open a new question to discuss this.

Comment: I am trying if and will present as a scala answer. Cannot find something like an array search for all cols.

Comment: I posted an intermediate solution as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala I did this differently, but got to this using pyspark. Not my favourite answer, but it is because of lesser pyspark knowledge my side. Things seem easier in Scala. Unlike an array there is no global match against all columns that can stop as soon as one found. Dynamic in terms of number of columns.

Assumptions made on data not having ~~ as part of data, could have split to array but decided not to do here. *Using None instead of NA*.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [(1,    None,    4,    None),
        (2,    'c',     3,    'd'),
        (None, None,    None, None),
        (3,    None,    None, 'z')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['k', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3'])

columns = df.columns
columns_Count = len(df.columns)

# colCompare is String
df2 = df.select(df['*'], f.concat_ws('~~', *columns).alias('colCompare') )
df3 = df2.filter(f.size(f.split(f.col("colCompare"), r"~~"))  == columns_Count).drop("colCompare")
df3.show()
```

returns:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  k| v1| v2| v3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  2|  c|  3|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to remove the row

```
df = df.filter((df.A != 'NA') | (df.B != 'NA'))
```

But sometimes we need to replace with mean(in case of numeric column) or most frequent value(in case of categorical). for that you need to add column with same name which replace the original column i-e "A"

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean,col,when,count
df=df.withColumn("A",when(df.A=="NA",mean(df.A)).otherwise(df.A))
```

Comment: Instead of |  it should be &

Comment: & will be used if both columns have 'NA' values in row, here | is used to filter if there is any of both has 'NA' value